# Setting Android Manifest Tags Dynamically

Tags: java, android

In particular, I want to know if its possible to set

```
android:exported="true"
```

dynamically or via Java.

Say something like below

```
public class Foo extends Service

@Override
public void onCreate() {
     super.onCreate();
     ***this.setExported(true);***
}
```

Comment: I am pretty sure that you can't change `android:exported` at runtime. You *can* change `android:enabled` at runtime, via `PackageManager` and `setComponentEnabledSetting()`. What scenario do you have where you only sometimes want third-party apps to be able to initiate communications with your component?

Comment: I can't really think of how to explain it.

Basically I have created a small library, which contains a service. If i extend that service in the app that include the library, I would have to set the exported tag, everytime I extend the service, instead of letting the library set it each time super is called.

if that makes sense at all